# How can Chrome extensions basically cURL other pages?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, browser-extension

I'm thinking about writing a Chrome extension that will need to, on a certain dynamic page of a certain site, grab a few links and analyze the contents of the linked pages.

I actually don't know much about writing browser extensions, so I wanted to see if it was doable before I committed myself to learning how. I do know that extensions typically execute Javascript but I am unaware of how to get that sort of result with Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Use jquery ajax to fetch the content of other pages.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [jQuery](http://jquery.com) and [this plugin](http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/cross-domain-requests-with-jquery/) by [James Padolsey](http://james.padolsey.com) to make a cross domain request; the plugin will return the page contents. You can then do something like this to get it into a jQuery object:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://example.com',
    type: 'GET',
    success: function(res) {
        var contents = $(res.responseText);
    }
});
```

With that contents object you can do anything you would do normally with a jQuery object, such as [`find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/). For instance, if you wanted to get the title of the page, you could do:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://example.com',
    type: 'GET',
    success: function(res) {
        var contents = $(res.responseText);
        var title = contents.find('title').text();
    }
});
```

Comment: Chrome extensions can perform [cross-domain requests](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/xhr.html) via host permsiions; no jQuery plugin required.