# Google Chrome Extension Http request

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'd like to know if Google Chrome Extension can make a HTTP request and parse the body of the result (like Curl).  For example, there is a server 1.2.3.4 that answers the question `?a=1&b=2` by summarizing the URL parameters.  The query `"http://1.2.3.4?a=1&b=2"` would return a body containing `3`, and my extension wants to submit such a query and parse the result.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Exact duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10769924/how-can-chrome-extensions-basically-curl-other-pages, but the answers on that version are pretty sub-optimal -- one is a non-answer and the other is inappropriately written in jQuery.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, using [Cross-Origin XMLHttpRequest](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/xhr.html).

1. Set the [permissions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31799066) in `manifest.json`
2. Then use it like this in your extension page:

   ```js
   var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
   xhr.open("GET", "http://api.example.com/data.json", true);
   xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
     if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
       // WARNING! Might be injecting a malicious script!
       document.getElementById("resp").innerHTML = xhr.responseText;
       ...
     }
   }
   xhr.send();
   ```

Notes:

- Content scripts can't make cross-origin requests in modern Chrome, [more info](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55292071).
- ManifestV3 background script doesn't have XMLHttpRequest so you will use [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/fetch) there.