# How do I send an HTTP request from a Chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, xmlhttprequest

I'm working on a chrome extension that sends a HTTP request.

How do I send it to `www.example.com` with the parameter `par` with value `0`?

```
https://www.example.com?par=0
```

(the server reads the parameter `par` and does something)

I found this article, talking about [Cross-Origin XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/xhr), but I don't know how their example could help me.

Answer (score 128, accepted):

First, you'll need to edit your `manifest.json` and add the permission for `www.example.com`:

- For the new [Manifest V3](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/intro/), use the `host_permissions` field:

  ```json
  {
      "manifest_version": 3,
      ...
      "host_permissions": [
          "https://www.example.com/*"
      ],
      ...
  }
  ```
- If you are still using the old Manifest V2, use the `permissions` field:

  ```json
  {
      "manifest_version": 2,
      ...
      "permissions": [
          "https://www.example.com/*"
      ],
      ...
  }
  ```

Then in your background page (or somewhere else) you can do:

```
fetch('http://www.example.com?par=0').then(r => r.text()).then(result => {
    // Result now contains the response text, do what you want...
})
```

See also [MDN doc for `fetch()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/fetch).

---

Deprecated version using `XMLHttpRequest` (ES5):

```
function callback() {
    if (xhr.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
        if (xhr.status === 200) {
            result = xhr.responseText;
            // ...
        }
    }
};

var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("GET", "http://www.example.com?par=0", true);
xhr.onreadystatechange = callback;
xhr.send();
```

**NOTE** the warning at the top of the relative [documentation page](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/xhr):

> In Manifest V3, `XMLHttpRequest` is not supported in background pages (provided by Service Workers). Please consider using its modern replacement, `fetch()`

Comment: Just as a note: If you are on an https page and you are requesting an http URL, you might get a `Mixed Content: The page at '...' ` error.

Comment: Can I add a pattern instead a specific domain?

Comment: Yes you can, using * wildcards. If you want to allow acces over https and http though, you'll have to add that separately. Read https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/xhr

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34627921/synchronous-xmlhttprequest-on-the-main-thread-is-deprecated-tried-many-differ, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11506687/google-chrome-extension-http-request

Comment: I got a CORB error trying to call `fetch` from my content script (adding external URL to `permissions` array does not solve the problem). The following answer solved my problem, which was to delegate the fetch call to a background script and send parsing the response back in the content script as originally intended. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55214828/how-to-stop-corb-from-blocking-requests-to-data-resources-that-respond-with-cors/55215898#55215898

Comment: Property has been renamed from `permissions` => `host_permissions`

Comment: is it possible to use axios? fetch did not contain interceptor. @Marco Bonelli

Comment: @liangqicai Not sure honestly as I have never used it. You will have to do some googling to figure that out...