# Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated... Tried many different solution

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I know this question was posted so many times in here, but I tried all the solutions I could find on stack overflow and none of them worked.
I'm just trying to make a simple ajax query to load a page inside a div.
Just as simple as:

```
function loadHome(){
$('#container').html('<div class="loader"></div>');
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "home.php",
        success: function(msg){
            $("#container").html(msg);
        }
});
}
```

And on the console log I get

> Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help, check http://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/

And some of my javascript on the home page will not work unless I reload the page. That page is by default loading `home.php` inside the div already, but I want it to load other pages and then when I click "home" it should load normally, and that's not happening because of that error. I already tried to use "async: true", didn't work. I don't know what to do.

Comment: try by using `async: false`

Comment: @ParthTrivedi - No!!!!!!   `async:false` is a horrible recommendation.  It's a hack, leads to bad user experience and is not needed with proper async coding.

Comment: @ParthTrivedi that's why the warning arises.

Comment: The code you show in your question does not lead to the message you show about synchronous XMLHttpRequest so something is wrong in your question.

Comment: Try finding if you used any `.ajaxSetup()` method and check for  `async:false` there.

Comment: @jfriend00 But the message pops up as soon as I hit the "home" button, could it be the home php page showing the error?

Comment: Yes some of your script get used as  `async:false` in `home.php`

Comment: @ParthTrivedi well, I coded all the pages myself. I didnt set async: false in any of my scripts

Comment: This can occurs if any of your `script` in `home.php` get run before your included `script` (cdn js) files loaded to `DOM`.

Comment: Please can you write code what are the `script` you have included in `home.php` so someone can help you to fix this.

Comment: My "home.php" has no javascript in it but I just noticed that this only happens when calling pages that include chat.php. And My chat php is: `<div id="chat" class="chat">
<form autocomplete="off" id="message-form" onSubmit="javascript:void(0);">
<div class="chat-message" id="chat-message">
</div>
<input id="send-message" placeholder="Message...">
</form>
</div>
 <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
 <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
 <script src="js/chat.js"></script>`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99898/discussion-between-parth-trivedi-and-marciel-fonseca).

Comment: chat.js: is too long to post in here, but it's just dome socket.io client connection and emit code

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript console.log causes error: "Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated..."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24639335/javascript-console-log-causes-error-synchronous-xmlhttprequest-on-the-main-thr)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use local jquery then from `cdn` and also

To avoid this warning, do not use:

```
async: false
```

in any of your `$.ajax()` calls. This is the only feature of `XMLHttpRequest` that's deprecated.

The default is `async: true`, so if you never use this option at all, your code should be safe if the feature is ever really removed (it probably won't be -- it may be removed from the standards, but I'll bet browsers will continue to support it for many years).

[Referance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27736186/jquery-has-deprecated-synchronous-xmlhttprequest?answertab=active#tab-top)

Answer (score 1):

I also notice the same problem when using the .load() function.

The method seems not deprecated by jquery but it causes Synchronous XMLHttpRequest alert too.

Prefer $.get(), $.post(), or $.ajax() methods instead.