# JavaScript fails on sending GET requests to my server

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon-webextensions

I have this code:

```
function httpGetAsync(theUrl, callback)
{
    var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function() { 
        if (xmlHttp.readyState == 4 && xmlHttp.status == 200)
            callback(xmlHttp.responseText);
    }
    xmlHttp.open("GET", theUrl, true); // true for asynchronous 
    xmlHttp.send(null);
}

 httpGetAsync("http://myserver.com/test.php/?u=test&p=testtest");
```

when I try to run it on Firefox's console, I get:

> `NetworkError: A network error occurred.`

Why does this happen? How can I fix this?

Comment: what is filename you are submitting your request to? It's not incuded in URL path.

Comment: @HamzaRashid `ŧest.php` is the filename I'm submitting my request to.

Comment: make sure your file is present on the server and is publically accessible.

Comment: @HamzaRashid it is. I already tried to manually send the request using the browser, and it worked perfectly.

Comment: there shouldn't be `/` between filename `test.php` and `?`. it should be `http://myserver.com/test.php?u=test&p=testtest`

Comment: @HamzaRashid it doesn't work too.

Comment: i suggest you run your `JS` code on localhost instead of Firefox console.

Comment: Also, fetch. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch

Comment: @HamzaRashid what changes? I don't have a webserver because I don't need to. I need to send my GET request from my extension, but I'm trying to run it in the console firstly; it doesn't work yet.

Comment: Do you know XMLHttpRequest require server environment to run successfully something like `WAMP/MAMP/LAMP`, `NodeJS` etc in case of localhost or live host.

Comment: @HamzaRashid I don't want it to require a server. How can I send a GET request without this?

Comment: Sending request is fine, you can simply send `GET` request by visiting your URL in browser location bar. Request sends request ok. But problem is when you get response. Response requires hosting environment.

Comment: Copy/Paste your URL in browser location bar.

Comment: @HamzaRashid I don't need a response. I need to make just the request to my server. Copying/pasting my URL on my browser location bar shows me it works.

Comment: Now you made clear that you are developing a browser extension. See my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Sending `GET` request if you are developing a browser extension**

Go to your `manifest.json` file and add permission for `www.example.com`:

```
{
    "name": "My extension",
    ...
    "permissions": [
        "http://www.example.com/*"
    ],
    ...
}
```

Then in your background page (or somewhere else) you can do:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("GET", "http://www.example.com/test.php?foo=bar", false);
xhr.send();

var result = xhr.responseText;
```

**Reference**

[How do I send an HTTP GET request in chrome extension?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25107774/how-do-i-send-an-http-get-request-in-chrome-extension/25107925#25107925)

Comment: pleasure helping you.